# Bootstrap 3 two columns full height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a two-column **full-height** layout with Twitter Bootstrap 3. It seems that **Twitter Bootstrap 3** does not support full height layouts.
What I want to do:

```
  +-------------------------------------------------+
  |                     Header                      |
  +------------+------------------------------------+
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |Navigation  |         Content                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  +------------+------------------------------------+
```

If the content grows, the `nav` should also grow.

- Height 100% for every parent doesn't work because there is the case where content is one line.
- `position: absolute` seems to be the wrong way.
- `display: table` and `display: table-cell` solves the problem, but not elegantly.

###### HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is there way to make it with default **Twitter Bootstrap 3** classes?

Comment: Does that navigation + content element has to cover the remaining viewport (screen) height?

Comment: Yes. Just for clearing: header + content = 100% of viewport, if height of content  <= viewport height minus header height. sorry for poor english

Comment: I don't understand, couldn't you just give the background to the .row and allow the col-md-9 to cover up the portion or vice-versa? How about giving the row a height 100% giving the nav height 100% and just allow the col-md-9 to grow dynamically?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

**Edit:**
In [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/), native classes *can* produce full-height columns ([DEMO](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/eWBXoY?editors=1100)) because they changed [their grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) to flexbox. (Read on for Bootstrap 3)

---

The native Bootstrap 3.0 classes don't support the layout that you describe,  however, we can integrate some custom CSS which make use of [css tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display) to achieve this.

**[Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/kHARGhxbES)** / **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/pEZmmB)**

### Markup:

```
<header>Header</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 no-float">Navigation</div>
        <div class="col-md-9 no-float">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### (Relevant) CSS

```
html,body,.container {
    height:100%;
}
.container {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0; /*set left/right padding according to needs*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}

.row .no-float {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
```

The above code will achieve **full-height columns** (due to the custom css-table properties which we added) and with **ratio 1:3** (Navigation:Content) for **medium screen widths** and above - (due to bootstrap's default classes: col-md-3 and col-md-9)

**NB:**

**1)** In order not to mess up bootstrap's native column classes we add another class like `no-float` in the markup and only set `display:table-cell` and `float:none` on this class (as apposed to the column classes themselves).

**2)** If we only want to use the  css-table code for a specific break-point (say medium screen widths and above) but for mobile screens we want to default back to the usual bootstrap behavior than we can wrap our custom CSS within a media query, say:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row .no-float {
      display: table-cell;
      float: none;
  }
}
```

### [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/amJAxd)

Now, for smaller screens, the columns will behave like default bootstrap columns (each getting full width).

**3)** If the 1:3 ratio is necessary for all screen widths - then it's probably a better to remove bootstrap's col-md-* classes from the markup because that's not how they are meant to be used.

### [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/GjWbAG)

Comment: Hm. It is not really what I looking for, may be there is solution with native bootstrap 3 classes? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Works for me after adding float: none; to columns, but on js it is not necessary. Why? 
Upd: @media - cause

Comment: 2 minor things. 1) [the header and left navigation doesn't stick](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/scsGj/20/), (but maybe its okay with the OP) 2) [what if the header changes?](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/scsGj/21/) (again, maybe its okay with the OP)

Comment: It's not working for me, when i get more content on the screen, as the scrollbar then appears. When the scrollbar appears, my side navigation is no longer 100% height

Comment: So the answer would be : "No you can't do this with the bootstrap classes out of the box"  ?

Comment: @Lukas I am right there with you. 100 days at sea later I have reached land. Ahoy! Thank you Danield for this post, this answer saved me, the `.no-float` class and a few other modifications (adding some `height: 100%`'s to my columns) got me moving again. Innumerable infinite +1's to infinity and beyond.

Answer (score 71):

You can achieve what you want with the `padding-bottom: 100%; margin-bottom: -100%;` trick, has you can see in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/W29Wh/) fiddle.

I change your HTML a little bit, but you can achieve the same result with your own HTML with the following code

```
.col-md-9 {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.col-md-3 {
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100%;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I will update question. I have dynamic page (col-md-9 can grow), so, your variant shouldn't work, but I will test it. Thanks

Comment: Not something what I mean in question. I want full height columns, in case when col-md-9 have one line of text height all the same should be 100% - height of header or simple 100%. 
I'm tried this trick, only with values like 10000px, -10000px.
But thanks for your answer.

Comment: My columns were high, so I had to amend  
padding-bottom: 10000%;
margin-bottom: -10000%; 
and it did the trick. Otherwise I guess 100% has do do with page height

Comment: For others trying this solution, overflow: hidden needs to be applied to the parent row, not the non-sidebar column in order to work across browsers. It's correct in the fiddle, but not in the explanation above.

Answer (score 37):

### Pure CSS solution

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/58mkp/1/)

Using CSS2.1 only, Work with all browsers (IE8+), **without specifying any height or width.**

That means that if your header suddenly grows longer, or your left navigation needs to enlarge, you don't have to fix **anything** in your CSS.

Totally responsive, simple & clear and very easy to manage.

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Header">
    </div>
    <div class="HeightTaker">
        <div class="Wrapper">
            <div class="LeftNavigation">
            </div>
            <div class="Content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**
The container `div` takes 100% height of the body, and he's divided into 2 sections.
The header section will span to its needed height, and the `HeightTaker` will take the rest.
How is it achieved? by floating an empty element along side the container with 100% height (using `:before`), and giving the `HeightTaker` an empty element at the end with the clear rule (using `:after`). that element cant be in the same line with the floated element, so he's pushed till the end. which is exactly the 100% of the document.

With that we make the `HeightTaker` span the rest of the container height, without stating any specific height/ margin.

inside that `HeightTaker` we build a normal floated layout (to achieve the column like display) with a minor change.. we have a `Wrapper` element, that is needed for the `100%` height to work.

### Update

[**Here's**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/vtxnF/10/) the Demo with Bootstrap classes. (I just added one div to your layout)

Comment: Yes, it is the most beauty solution. Could you make it for bootstrap classes?

Comment: And please, explain, how it works. currently it is most suitable to approve

Comment: I don't know bootstrap.. sorry. but its so easy to use.. you can do it by yourself. I will add an explanation of how it works.

Comment: @baxxabit I added an explanation. tell me if you need more info.

Comment: Please, try to make fiddle like http://jsfiddle.net/zrBGw/129/light/ with your solution and bootstrap template. I will accept your answer if it works

Comment: The problem with this solution is when your navigation or content container is bigger than viewport you will have two separated scrolls.  http://jsfiddle.net/58mkp/2/

Comment: @OswaldoAcauan I actually make that on purpose. and that can be changed if the OP wants it. in the current behavior, the Content can grow without affecting the Navigation. It's a 2 click change if the OP wants it..

Comment: @baxxabit I've updated my solution with a Fiddle for Bootstrap template. (caution: I add one other div)

Comment: How to avoid position: absolute? In this case display: table looks like only working solution.

Comment: what's the problem? it's a absolute position that fill his parent entirely. the flow of the page remains intact. the only reason that he's absolute is to make the browser calculate his height after the parent. do you have a problem with that layout? can you provide an img of that problem?

Comment: sorry, yes, I have a problem. please, look at fiddle with included bootstrap css http://jsfiddle.net/vtxnF/6/

Comment: OK. I overridden all the thing that was in the way.. try it now. (I've updated the solution)

Comment: Sorry, the another problem http://d.pr/i/lh7B. Seems that tables are the best solution

Comment: just needed to add `overflow:auto;` I updated the fiddle. @baxxabit if you don't get why this is a better solution.. you can use tables.. do whatever you need. just read my comment on his solution. and remember that all the problems is because you choose to add `bootstrap` so I need to override some of the css.. you should compare to my pure solution.. (it's not hard to override the bootstrap, just need to try it on the fly)

Comment: Ok, @avrahamcool, my original problem is to make two columns with default bootstrap classes, not position: absolute for wrapper, not display: tables. I'm wondering with technique to use :after and :before for this, but I need working solution. There is several techniques for displaying two columns layout, I want to get less overriding css class for aiming. Thanks for your solution. Best regards

Comment: OK.. so use one of the many answer you got here.. or mine.. whatever suits you best. good luck.

Comment: The `<kbd>` tag is used to denote user input. Please do not use it to wrap links.

Comment: With Twitter Bootstrap 3, removing `float: left;` for navigation div will make content go under navigation on smaller devices as intended by the framework.

Comment: If you resize the window it would not be fit properly on screen.

Comment: @Sirlate what resolution did you try? for me it's working fine.

Comment: @avrahamcool If you reduce the size of you browser width, you would see that the `content` section wont fit into the screen and it will be gone.

Comment: @Sirlate no, the `content` doesn't disappear it goes under the navigation.

Comment: @avrahamcool, this solution now doesn't fit boostrap 3.3.4(the latest one).

Answer (score 26):

I thought about a subtle change, which doesn't change the default bootstrap behavior.
And I can use it only when I needed it:

```
.table-container {
  display: table;
}

.table-container .table-row {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}

.table-container .table-row .table-col {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

so I can have use it like this:

```
<div class="container table-container">
  <div class="row table-row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 table-col"> ... </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 table-col"> ... </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 table-col"> ... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked beautifully for me (using bootstrap 3)

Comment: I couldn't get one of the above solutions to work, vertical-align was the key for me.

Answer (score 11):

Modern and very simple solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: row is still 0px high

Answer (score 9):

To my knowledge you can use up to 5 methods to accomplish this:

1. Using the CSS display table/table-cell properties or using actual tables.
2. Using an absolute positioned element inside the wrapper.
3. Using the Flexbox display property but, as of today, it still has [partial support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)
4. Simulate full column heights by using the [faux column technique](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns).
5. Using the padding/margin technique. [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/scsGj/19/).

Bootstrap: I don't have much experience with it but I don't think they provide styles for that.

```
.row
{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
.row .col-md-3,
.row .col-md-9 
{
    padding: 30px 3.15% 99999px; 
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
}
.row .col-md-3 p,
.row .col-md-9 p 
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.col-md-3
{
    background: pink;
    left:0;
    width:25%
}
.col-md-9
{
    width: 75%;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Oriol. You are awesome.
Some points:
1),2) yes, but not what I want 
3) It is a solution, but only for modern ff and chrome. safari support an old version of flexbox
4) not the bootstrap classes
5) Right columns can grow. So overflow: hidden will crop an important lines. It is not cool :)

I will try your code

Answer (score 7):

A pure CSS solution is easy enough and it works like a charm cross browser.

You simply add a large padding and an equally large negative margin to the nav and content columns, then wrap their row in a class with overflow hidden.
[Live view](http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/dGY9g/show/)
[Edit view](http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/dGY9g/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row col-wrap">

    <div class="col-md-3 col">
      <h1>Nav</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9 col">
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col{
margin-bottom: -99999px;
padding-bottom: 99999px;
}

.col-wrap{
overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: sorry but that looks like a horrible hack which doesn't give you the options for absolute positioning an element at bottom of the child container.

Comment: Not good solution if you have bottom border radius or some kind of visual asset in div background.

Answer (score 5):

The solution can be achieved in two ways

1. Using display:table and display:table-cell
2. Using padding and negative margin.

The classes which are used to obtain the above solution are not provided in bootstrap 3.
display:table and display:table-cell are given but only when using tables in HTML.
negative margin and padding classes are also not there.

Hence we have to use custom css to achieve this.

The below is the first solution

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>Page-Header</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row tablewrapper">
    <div class="col-md-12 tablerowwrapper">
        <div class="col-md-3 sidebar pad_top15">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Submenuone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenutwo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenuthree</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 content">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

the corresponding css:

```
html,body,.container{
        height:100%;
    }
    .tablewrapper{
        display:table;
        height:100%;
    }
    .tablerowwrapper{
        display:table-row;
    }
    .sidebar,.content{
        display:table-cell;
        height:100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        float:none;
    }
    .pad_top15{
        padding-top:15px;
    }
```

The below is the second solution

HTML code:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>Page-Header</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ovfhidden bord_bot height100p">
    <div class="col-md-3 sidebar pad_top15">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Submenuone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenutwo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenuthree</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 content pad_top15">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div><div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div><div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div><div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div><div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div><div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div><div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
  </div>

</div>
```

the corresponding css:

```
html,body,.container{
        height:100%;
    }
    .sidebar,.content{
        /*display:table-cell;
        height:100%;*/
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding-bottom:8000px;
        margin-bottom:-8000px;
    }
    .ovfhidden{
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .pad_top15{
        padding-top:15px;
    }
    .bord_bot{
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
```

Comment: Columns not have 100% height of viewport

Comment: sorry forgot a basic style html,body,container{ height:100%;} add this style to the first solution

Comment: right column can grow, so overflow:hidden for row can crop some content, if it will take more than height of viewport.

Comment: remove overflow:hidden from row. there is hidden content
http://jsfiddle.net/gMPXG/7/embedded/result/

Comment: What is the problem in that??

Comment: Sorry, if not clear. I want columns with height = 100% of viewport minus height of header

Comment: in such a situation we have to go with display:table; and display:table-cell; method

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I've achieved the same thing using **Bootstrap 3.0**

**Example with the latest bootstrap**

http://jsfiddle.net/HDNQS/1/

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
    whatever
</div>
<div class="container-fluid wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 navigation"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9 content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The SCSS:**

```
html, body, .wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

$headerHeight: 43px;

.navigation, .content {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -$headerHeight;
    padding-top: $headerHeight;
}

.header {
    height: $headerHeight;
}

.row {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: table-row;
    &:before, &:after {
        content: none;
    }
}

.navigation {
    background: #4a4d4e;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it is the same as approved answer. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's mostly the same but you need to add some little "tweakings"(see `content:none` and other small things). I wanted to post a 'drop-in' replacement that I can copypasta aswell

Comment: +1 for the addition of "vertical-align: top". My left hand column was stuck at the bottom of the page until I added this.

Answer (score 3):

So it seems your best option is going with the `padding-bottom` countered by negative `margin-bottom` strategy.

I made two examples. One with `<header>` **[inside](http://jsfiddle.net/scsGj/25/)** `.container`, and another with it **[outside](http://jsfiddle.net/scsGj/26/)**.

Both versions should work properly. Note the use of the following `@media` query so that it removes the extra padding on smaller screens...

```
@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
    .content { padding-top:0; }
}
```

Other than that, those examples should fix your problem.

Comment: good call on removing the extra padding on smaller screens gio

Comment: Thumbs up for the fiddle with the outside header, this was the only one working for my case.

Answer (score 2):

there's a much easier way of doing this if all you're concerned about is laying down the colour.

Put this either first or last in your body tag

```
<div id="nfc" class="col col-md-2"></div>
```

and this in your css

```
#nfc{
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -99;
}
```

you're just creating a shape, pinning it behind the page and stretching it to full height.  By making use of the existing bootstrap classes, you'll get the right width and it'll stay responsive.

There are some limitations with this method ofc, but if it's for the page's root structure, it's the best answer.

Comment: Why do you have `position: absolute`, then `position: fixed`?

Comment: haven't the foggiest, typo :)

Comment: Nice solution. However, I can only get it to line up correctly using `.container-fluid`. I'd like to use `.container`. Ideas?

Comment: `.container` or `.container-fluid` have no relevance to this at all.  the `.col.col-md-2` sets the width using bootstrap.  My CSS above forces the div to full height, with sufficient negative z-index to make sure it's behind everything.  As stated above, it should be the very first, or the very last element in your `<body>` tag

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">header section</div>

    </div>
     <div class="row fill">
        <div class="col-md-4">Navigation</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">Content</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

css for .fill class is below

```
 .fill{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;
    background: blue;
}
.col-md-12
{
    background: red;

}

.col-md-4
{
    background: yellow;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;

}
.col-md-8
{
    background: green;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;

}
```

For your reference just look into the [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zrBGw/129/embedded/result/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I use twitter bootstrap 3, not 2. Please, read http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration

Comment: bootstrap 3, no span is used, changed to col.

Comment: Ok. Height of columns will be as height of content in columns, but I can have only one line.

Comment: Thanks @Kooki3. Just change `span` to `col-md-` and lets see what happens `<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">header section</div>

    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">Navigation</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">Content</div>

    </div>
</div>`

Comment: doesn't work. Do you read my comment? http://jsfiddle.net/YQUQd/1/embedded/result/

Comment: @baxxabit I changed my answer. Can you try it http://jsfiddle.net/zrBGw/129/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <div class="container">
     <!-- Header-->         
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span3 well">
         <ul class="nav nav-list">
             <li class="nav-header">Our Services</li>
                <!-- Navigation  -->
             <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Android Applications</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="span7 offset1">
      <!-- Content -->         
     </div>
 </div>
```

Visit http://www.sitepoint.com/building-responsive-websites-using-twitter-bootstrap/

Thanks to Syed

Comment: Thanks, could you change your example for bootstrap 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple CSS compatible with Bootstrap to create full width and height tables:

**Fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/uasbfc5e/4/

The principle is :

- add the "tablefull" on a main DIV
- then implicitly, the DIV below will create rows
- and then DIV below the rows will be cells
- You can use the class "tableheader" for headers or similar

**The HTML :**

```
<div class="tablefull">
    <div class="tableheader">
        <div class="col-xs-4">Header A</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">B</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">C</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">Content 50% width auto height</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">Hello World</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">Content 70% width auto height</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">Merry Halloween</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
div.tablefull {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.tablefull>div.tableheader, div.tablefull>div.tableheader>div{
    height: 0%;
}

div.tablefull>div {
    display: table-row;
}

div.tablefull>div>div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Beware of CSS minifiers, sometime they change `0%;` to `0;` which is totally different. If that happens, you can use `1%;` instead.

Answer (score -1):

If there will be no content after the row (whole screen height is taken), the trick with using `position: fixed; height: 100%` for `.col:before` element may work well:

```css
header {
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
}
.col-xs-3 {
  background: pink;
}
.col-xs-3:before {
  background: pink;
  content: ' ';
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -15px; /* compensates column's padding */
  position: fixed;
  width: inherit; /* bootstrap column's width */
  z-index: -1; /* puts behind content */
}
.col-xs-9 {
  background: yellow;
}
.col-xs-9:before {
  background: yellow;
  content: ' ';
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -15px; /* compensates column's padding */
  position: fixed;
  width: inherit; /* bootstrap column's width */
  z-index: -1; /* puts behind content */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header>Header</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">Navigation</div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This was not mentioned here with offsetting.

You can use absolute to position for the left sidebar.

*CSS*

```
.sidebar-fixed{
  width: 16.66666667%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="sidebar-fixed">
    Side Bar
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
    CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">Nav     Content</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">Content goes here</div>
</div>
```

This uses Bootstrap 3 so no need for extra CSS etc...

Comment: please, provide fiddle

Comment: Here is a sample showing something like this from the Bootstrap website: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Answer (score -3):

Have you seen the  the bootstrap's ***afix***  in the JAvascript's section ???

I think it would be the best & easiest solution dude.

Have a look there : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Comment: Can you please share example, how can I make two columns with afix?

Comment: By the way.... did you try with the  min-height ??? Maybe it's usefull, right ?@baxxabit

Answer (score -3):

After experimenting with the code provided here: [Bootstrap Tutorial](http://cyberdesigncraft.com/bootstrap-3-grid-tutorial/)

Here is another alternative using latest [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.0.2/bootstrap-3.0.2-dist.zip) v3.0.2:

**Markup:**

```
<div id="headcontainer" class="container">
           <p>Your Header</p>    
</div>
<div id="maincontainer" class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-4"> 
            <p>Your Navigation</p> 
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-8"> 
            <p>Your Content</p> 
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

**Additional CSS:**

```
#maincontainer, #headcontainer {
width: 100%;
}

#headcontainer {
background-color:#CCCC99; 
height: 150px
}

#maincontainer .row .col-xs-4{
background-color:gray; 
height:1000px
}

#maincontainer .row .col-xs-8{
background-color:green;
height: 1000px
}
```

Sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zHRZr/4/)

Hope this helps anyone interested.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zHRZr/7/ original question about dynamic height, but thanks anyway