# Full height does not work when adding bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I used the example here

[Twitter bootstrap 3 two columns full height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089384/twitter-bootstrap-3-two-columns-full-height)

I just added bootstrap.css in the file

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/scsGj/136/

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

If I run in jsfiddle, it's fine. But if I run outside of jsfiddle, it doesn't have full height any more. See: http://jsfiddle.net/m/jva/

Any suggestion on why is this the problem?

Comment: Can you please include the code in your post rather than forcing people to look somewhere else for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if you expand the width past a certain point, the issue is reproduced.

The offending bootstrap css is located inside of a media query that floats the affected elements.

```
 @media(min-width:992px) {

 .col-md-1,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-      9,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12 {
       float: left
   }
```

I was able to find the issue by examining the computed style of the element in chrome dev tools as I changed `th` window width.

Here is a fix:

```
.row > div {
float:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scsGj/138/