# Several questions about Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

1. Bootstrap.js: does it contain javascript already or do I need to install it like I ussualy do? If I do what bootstrap.js actually contain then?
2. I put this in class col-xs-6 when I want to make some element 50% weight of screen, right? What is used for height then? And I put that in class, correct? For example ?

3.How can I edit some element that comes with bootstrap? For example when you putting button with "btn" bootstrap class should I make some class for it or I should edit it directly from bootstrap.css?

1. Is weight of one grid aproximetly 8,33% size of screen?
2. Is grid(col-xs-12) used for height always to make responsive design or sometimes I should use weight:100% for example?

Comment: How do you normally install JavaScript, I'm intrigued?

Comment: download javascript file, and insert it in head like you do with css :D

Answer (score 0):

First question:

If you need Bootstrap plugins, you'll be also needing jQuery, if that's what you mean by javascript. [BS docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/):

> Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files).

Other questions:

If I'm not mistaken Bootstrap does not support setting height, say, to 100% of parent container. There are [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089384/twitter-bootstrap-3-two-columns-full-height), though.

Then again, if you meant "width", then yes, you get full width with col-xs-12. But bear in mind that most block-level elements, like div, have 100% width by default.

When using col-xs-1, or similar classes, each column's width is not exactly 8,33% because negative margins of each row of and possible margins between columns.