# Bootstrap two columns layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with bootstrap columns. I want to do something like
this picture and I don't know how to do it.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Can you post code samples, or an explanation of what you've tried so far?

Comment: i tried to do this in pingendo, but it's only begin of my work with this editor. And i have no code.
I tried to do two columns and in second column another columns but it was not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap 3 two columns full height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089384/twitter-bootstrap-3-two-columns-full-height)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the grid layout to give you something like:

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div>Big Image Goes Here</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div class="col-xs-12">Little Image #1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-12">Little Image #2</div>
     <div class="col-xs-12">Little Image #3</div>
     <div class="col-xs-12">Little Image #4</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

However, you would need to add some padding to the images to give them the white area around them.

The grid layout is explained here:
[bootstrap grid layout](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Here is a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kgjertsen/Ldx0z4ga/).

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is made up of 12 columns in a row. If you want something to display half and half for example, the first element would have a value of six like so: `class="col-xs-6"`and the second would be the same. To learn bootstrap really well make [this](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) site your best friend.

For a demo to your solution click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/coozin/orrzjh59/)

Here we have your HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-7 left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5 right">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5 right">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5 right">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5 right">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left{
    float: left; 
}
.right{
    float: right; 
}
div{
    padding: 20px; 
}
```

There is probably already a class for floating objects in bootstrap I just couldn't remember exactly, so I did it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a div with two columns: left and right with same class created for columns (for example `.col-md-3`). Then in right column add four rows. Example is [here](http://www.bootply.com/xfgdwWaeNV).