# How to divide a row into two columns using div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Following is my code and how to divide into two columns:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-8">
            <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
                <label>Promotional Code</label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
                <label>Promotional Code</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using flex styles for displaying a row with two columns

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
          <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
               <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                    <label>Promotional Code</label>
               </div>

               <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}> 
                    <label>Promotional Code</label>
               </div>
           </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
<div className="col-12 col-md-3">
```

to this:

```
<div className="col-6 col-md-3">
```

---

`col-12` is you can say 100% of the width then to break it in half you can use `col-6`. [You can check this to learn more about 12 column layout](https://www.unco.edu/web-communications/blog/understanding-the-12-column-grid.aspx).

Note:-  If you want it to be in two columns in each devices then you have to use different classes on the single node like:

- `col-6 col-lg-6` - for desktops
- `col-md-6` - for tablets
- `col-sm-6` - for phones

#### [*Another answer on SO for the same.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33498431/1059101)

Comment: @MadhumiMunasinghe can you elaborate more about this. _still not working_....doesn't help to give you a better answer.

Comment: @MadhumiMunasinghe Only on the 2 divs that are around the `<label>Promotional Code </label>`. Not the parent div of those 2

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below one -

```
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
          <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <label>Promotional Code</label>
          </div>

          <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <label>Promotional Code</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I replaced but still it gives the same output. The divs are not separated to two columns

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-3">
          <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
            <label>Promotional Code</label>
          </div>

          <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-3">
            <label>Promotional Code</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 </form>
```

For More Help:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hi use flex as it gives more flexibility if you have nested row columns

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
          <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>
              <div>
                <div>Promotional Code</div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div>Promotional Code</div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `.d-flex .flex-row`. Like below:

   `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}>
           <div className="row no-gutters">
             <div className="col-12 col-md-8">
               <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                 <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
                   <label>Promotional Code</label>
                 </div>
                 <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
                   <label>Promotional Code</label>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </form>`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please edit your answer, as it currently stand it is not possible to understand what the code does. Provide an example and an explanation to your solution.