# Can't make bootstrap columns full height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get my columns to full height. They are both slighty more then the total height and it's creating a vertical scroll bar.
I'm following this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089384/twitter-bootstrap-3-two-columns-full-height) answer.

The code below isn't working correctly if u run it, but this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/JWGRtosjQP) is demonstrating my issue correctly. The two columns run off the page at the bottom.

Here is my code and my [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/JWGRtosjQP)

Because I'm not that experienced with bootstrap, html and css
if there is a better way of doing this please let me know? Thanks!

My code snippet:

```css
html, body, .container-fluid {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .container-fluid {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: -50px;
            padding: 50px 0 0 0; 
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .row {
            height: 100%;
            display: table-row;
        }

        .col-sm-5 {
            background: pink;
            border: 1px solid purple;
        }

        .col-sm-7 {
            background: yellow;
        }

        .row .no-float {
            display: table-cell;
            float: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  
<div class="container-fluid wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5 no-float">map
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 no-float">events
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using CSS `calc()` will do the trick. This will help you eliminate the vertical scrollbar. Like:

```
html,body,.container {
    height: calc(100% - 18px);
}
```

Also remove the `margin-top: -50px` from the `.container`. Instead remove the `margin-bottom` from `nav.navbar`.

Have a look at the snippet below (*use full screen preview*):

```css
html,body,.container {
    height: calc(100% - 18px);
}
nav.navbar {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 !important; /*set left/right padding according to needs*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}

.col-md-3 {   
    background: pink;
}
.col-md-9 {
    background: yellow;   
}

.row .no-float {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 no-float">Navigation</div>
        <div class="col-md-9 no-float">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user1186050 Its the extra pixel height you are getting due to navbar, etc. Will refactor the code a little bit in 5 mins.

Comment: ok let me know when you have modified and cleaned up the code.

Comment: @user1186050 I've already done modifying the code a few mins ago.