# bootstrap column will not extend to the bottom of the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, viewport-units

I would like to know how I can get the sidebar on this bootstrap page to extend all the way to the bottom like the main column on the right. `height:vh` doesn't seem to work. Neither does `height:100%`.

Is this a bug in Bootstrap? I have never encountered this problem before. The sidebar has less content than the main sections, but I need for it to extend all the way to the bottom of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Column Test</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" style="border:2px solid red; margin:20px 0 20px 0; height:100%">
    <div class="row" style="border:2px solid black; height:100%">

        <!-- left-side (sidebar) -->
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: orange; height:100vh;">
            <div class="sidebar-container" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
                <h5 class="grey">TITLE 1</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li>item 1</li>
                    <li>item 2</li>
                    <li>item 3</li>
                    <li>item 4</li>
                    <li>item 5</li>
                    <li>item 6</li>
                    <hr>
                </ul>
                <h5>TITLE 2</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li>item 1</li>
                    <li>item 2</li>
                    <li>item 3</li>
                    <li>item 4</li>
                    <li>item 5</li>
                    <li>item 6</li>
                    <hr>
                </ul>
                <h5>TITLE 3</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li>item 1</li>
                    <li>item 2</li>
                    <li>item 3</li>
                    <li>item 4</li>
                    <li>item 5</li>
                    <li>item 6</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /leftside (sidebar) -->

        <!--right side (content)-->
        <div class="col-xs-9" style="background-color:pink; height:100%;">


            <div class=" row advertisement-container">
                <div class="col-md-1" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <h4>advertisement</h4>
                    <div class="advertisement"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            </div>



            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="col-md-12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>

                <div class="cme">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-1">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-2">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-3">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-4">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Stroke Systems of Care: Improving Outcomes</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-5">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Stroke Systems of Care: Improving Outcomes</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-6">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Stroke Systems of Care: Improving Outcomes</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-7">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Stroke Systems of Care: Improving Outcomes</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-8">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Stroke Systems of Care: Improving Outcomes</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-9">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Stroke Systems of Care: Improving Outcomes</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-10">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-11">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-12">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-13">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-14">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-15">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-16">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-17">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 cme-item cme-item-18">
                        <div class="cme-item-top">
                            <div class="cme-item-image">
                                <div class="cme-image-overlay">
                                    <p class="top-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <p class="bottom-text">3 Parts  |  3 Credits</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cme-item-bottom">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class=" row advertisement-container margin-bottom-20">
                <div class="col-md-1" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <h4>advertisement</h4>
                    <div class="advertisement"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            </div>

        </div> 
        <!--/right side-->

    </div>
</div>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>**strong text**
```

Comment: Please put it into a fiddle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap 3 two columns full height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089384/twitter-bootstrap-3-two-columns-full-height)

Comment: you can find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089384/twitter-bootstrap-3-two-columns-full-height